# @ngrx/effects: testing an effect returns empty()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx-effects

I am using @ngrx/effects 4.1.1. I have an effect that returns an empty observable like this:

```
@Effect() showDialog$: Observable<Action> = this
.actions$
.ofType( ActionTypes.DIALOG_SHOW )
.map( ( action: DialogAction ) => action.payload )
.switchMap( payload => {
    this.dialogsService.showDialog( payload.className );
    return empty();
} );
```

I am trying to write a unit test following [these guidelines](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/testing.md) that will test that the effect yields an empty observable. I have this:

```
describe( 'DialogEffects', () => {
    let effects: DialogEffects;
    let actions: Observable<any>;
    const mockDialogService = {
        showDialog: sinon.stub()
    };

    beforeEach( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            providers: [
                DialogEffects, provideMockActions( () => actions ),
                {
                    provide: DialogsService,
                    useValue: mockDialogService
                }
            ]
        } );

        effects = TestBed.get( DialogEffects );
    } );

    describe( 'showDialog$', () => {
        it( 'should return an empty observable', () => {
            const dialogName = 'testDialog';
            const action = showDialog( dialogName );

            actions = hot( '--a-', { a: action } );
            const expected = cold( '|' );

            expect( effects.showDialog$ ).toBeObservable( expected );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

However, Karma (v1.7.1) complains:

> Expected [  ] to equal [ Object({ frame: 0, notification: Notification({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false }) }) ].

How do I test that the effect returns `empty()`? I have tried modifying the effect metadata using `dispatch: false`, but this has no effect.

Ideas?

Comment: Your effect won't complete, so your cold observable should be `cold('');` - the pipe character represents the observable stream's completion.

Comment: Thanks cartant, that works now! You should post it and I will mark is as solved.

Comment: I assumed that empty() would immediately complete.

Comment: `switchMap` sees the empty observable (yes, it does complete) merged into the effect obsevable. The effect obsevable does not complete. Basically, you never want to complete an effect observable. If an effect does complete, it stops responding to actions.

Comment: So if the empty observable, which does complete, is merged into the effect observable, why does the effect observable not complete when it comes across this empty observable's complete?

Comment: Because if the merge were to complete (i.e. stop merging) when it sees the completion of a merged observable, it wouldn't be a merge - pretty much by definition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the actual result against `cold('|')`.

The pipe character in `cold('|')` represents the completion of the observable stream. However, your effect will not complete. The `empty()` observable does complete, but returning `empty()` from `switchMap` just sees that observable merged into the effect observable's stream - it does not complete the effect observable.

Instead, you should compare the actual result against `cold('')` - an observable that emits no values and does not complete.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to use dispatch false in the effect and change the swicthMap for a tap

```
@Effect({dispatch: false}) showDialog$ = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType( ActionTypes.DIALOG_SHOW ),
   map( ( action: DialogAction ) => action.payload ),
   tap( payload => 
      this.dialogsService.showDialog( payload.className )
    ));
```

To test it you can do  like

```
describe( 'showDialog$', () => {
    it( 'should return an empty observable', () => {
        const dialogName = 'testDialog';
        const action = showDialog( dialogName );
        actions = hot( '--a-', { a: action } );
        
       expect(effects.showDialog$).toBeObservable(actions);
// here use mock framework to check the dialogService.showDialog is called
    } );
} );
```

Notice the reason I use toBeObservable(actions) thats because due to disptach false this effect will not produce anything so actions is the same as before , what you gain by calling toBeObservable(actions) is that is makes the test synchronous, so you can check after it that your service was called with a mock framework like jasmine or ts-mockito

UPDATE

I think it is time to update this a bit, both ngrx and rxjs have changed, the way I will check an observable is empty today will be by :

```
describe( 'showDialog$', () => {
  it( 'should return an empty observable', async () => {
    const dialogName = 'testDialog';
    actions = of( showDialog( dialogName ) );
    const result  = await firstValueFrom( effects.showDialog$.pipe(isEmpty()) );
    expect( result ).toEqual( true );
  } );
} );
```

I don't tend to use Jasmine marbles any more, I generally only care about getting the last value of the effect and, jasmine marbles are overkill for that I only use them if I create custom operators,
async await and firstValueFrom is generally better for most common cases, and for empty, just adding a .pipe(isEmpty()) does the trick well

Comment: Do you have an idea how to verify that `{ dispatch: false }` is present. The test in your answer would still pass when `{ dispatch: false }` is removed from the effect.

Comment: Yes for versions before angular 8 you have https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing#geteffectsmetadata, to check that, but that only works for @Effect as far as I know , in 8 the recomended way is to use createEffect and not sure getEffectsMetadata works for it is omitted in the docs

Comment: Fun fact: we are using Angular and NgRx 8... So the question remains, how do we test this?

Comment: Hey I just happen to test getEffectsMetadata with an effects in angular 8  using the createEffect and it  still works, no idea why is not in the docs any more.

Comment: We will try that as well then! Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

To test that effect does not dispatch, you can assert against it's metadata with [getEffectsMetadata](https://ngrx.io/api/effects/getEffectsMetadata) function:

```
expect(getEffectsMetadata(effects).deleteSnapshotSuccess$?.dispatch).toBe(false)
```

The above has been tested with ngrx 9.0.0. Since all observables emit regardless of `dispatch`, checks like `expect(effects.effect$).toBeObservable(cold(''))` won't produce expected results.