# How to test with the marble approach when the returm is a EMPTY observable in effect?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, rxjs5, ngrx-effects, rxjs-marbles

I am using EMPTY from rxjs in order to handle the catchError, What is the correct value for expected in order to pass the fail scenario.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MoviesService } from './movies.service';

@Injectable()
export class MovieEffects {

  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
    mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      ))
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private moviesService: MoviesService
  ) {}
}
```

```
// unit test

it('should return a empty observable', () => {
   this.moviesServiceSpy.and.return(throwError('Error in service'));

   action$ = hot('a', a: { loadMovies() });

   const expected = cold('|');

   expect(loadMovies$).toBeObservable(expected);

})
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this myself and stumbled upon your question. I think I have an answer: Since `EMPTY` [immediately completes](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/empty) I took it to mean that 0 time passes. (EDIT: This was wrong!)

`EMPTY` or `empty()` by itself will match `cold('|')` or `hot('|')`. Read below for why it matches `cold('')` or `hot('')` in effects. (See the Examples section of [this RxJS documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing), which shows this as well.)

Confirmed by a [similar answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137400/100534), and now quoting the reason:

> The pipe character in `cold('|')` represents the completion of the observable stream. However, your effect will not complete. The `empty()` observable does complete, but returning `empty()` from `switchMap` just sees that observable merged into the effect observable's stream - it does not complete the effect observable.

So while `EMPTY` (or `empty()`) is documented to complete immediately, the end-result of its use in the effect indicates that the effect never completes.

Plugging this answer into your example:

```
it('should return a empty observable', () => {
   this.moviesServiceSpy.and.return(throwError('Error in service'));

   action$ = hot('a', a: { loadMovies() });

   const expected = cold('');

   expect(loadMovies$).toBeObservable(expected);

})
```

And just for fun, the following test passes too:

```
it('should match EMPTY with a single tick pipe marble', () => {
   expect(EMPTY).toBeObservable(cold('|'));
   expect(EMPTY).toBeObservable(hot('|'));

   // empty() is deprecated, but these assertions still pass.
   expect(empty()).toBeObservable(cold('|'));
   expect(empty()).toBeObservable(hot('|'));
});
```